# Test Open vSwitch vs Linux bridge vs Open vSwitch with DPDK

Tags: networking, 16.04

I have one quick question - how to test data flow in that environment? I have connection which look like this:

topology:
[image]

I want to test data flow from server1 to server2 through server3 which is Virtual Switch. All these servers are physical.

I want to test this in different environments, like OvS, OvS with DPDK then Linux bridge and I want to see any differences between them - but which traffic generator would be the best? I know only one - iperf.

I have seen some comparisons in Mpps between OvS and OvS with DPDK - but I only have seen end result, I haven't seen how looked like the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thanks for the drawing, that helps a lot.

I need to clarify - is it a mistake or really just one device in Server 2 as both sides are called "eth2"? I haven't seen bridging between to e.g. vlans with DPDK as that is at a higher level.
For now I'm assuming your Server 2 has two DPDK capable network devices (actually three to have one remaining for control).

You would then on server 2 dedicate both network devices to DPDK and add them to openvswitch. See the [Serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/DPDK.html#dpdk-openvswitch) for some examples. There is an update pending to integrate how this is done for the OVS/DPDK versions available in Yakkety.
OVS will naturally bridge traffic between those two ports without further configuration.

Warning: make sure those two ports are not part of the same physical network. Doing so would re-reflect all traffic and self amplify itself - finally killing the whole network segment with this being a self made DOS attack.

Once you have set this up, you can run any sort of traffic from server 1 <-> server 3. Iperf is fine for simple streaming workloads. Other common simple tests are netperf and uperf. Configuring all three can be found in the test examples linked [here](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-server/ubuntu/+source/dpdk-testing/+git/dpdk-testing).

For some simplified testing on Ubuntu which can be done on just one machine with two DPDK capable ports feel free to take a look at [simple dpdk tests](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-server/ubuntu/+source/dpdk-testing/+git/dpdk-testing). Some day I intend to set up something similar to your drawing in that with virtual machines to then modify flow rules in between and check the impact of number and complexity of them, but had no time yet.

Finally if you want to go bigger you could consider using server 1 (if enough interfaces are available) with a DPDK based traffic generator like for example [Moongen](https://github.com/emmericp/MoonGen) or [TRex](https://trex-tgn.cisco.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response.

Yes, my mistake, here you are new topology:

new_topology:
[new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwDKF.png)

In server3 I have one NIC (with eth1 and eth2 ports) and then I have connection from server1 to the eth2 on that NIC and from server2 to the eth1 on the same NIC.

I have only one Network interface card (NIC) on server3. 
I found some examples of comparisons, for example Open vSwitch vs Linux bridge vs Open vSwitch with DPDK and here you are some example of result:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgBEl.png)

I want to achieve sth like that, but I don't know which traffic generator I should use..

Comment: I listed the obvious traffic gen up there that are usually used with DPDK support. But those usually would all run on one system and provide the in and out so it would look like.
Trafficgen-eth1->server-eth1->server-eth2->trafficgen-eth2

But for a start with simpler things take the simple tools I listed above, netperf/uperf are available in the archive. You can still grow from there.

If money isn't that important I see many people use https://www.ixiacom.com/products/ixnetwork